# Orthographic Camera Projection matrix

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, orthographic

**The goal**

I'm trying to implement an orthographic camera for 2D rendering with OpenGL.

**The issue**

Nothing is drawn to the screen.

**The setup**

Each frame I am updating the camera using this call:

```
updateCamera(&gCamera, -10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
```

The updateCamera method has the following declaration:

```
void updateCamera(Camera* cam, float top, float bottom, float left, float right, float zFar, float zNear);
```

The camera struct simply has a `float opm[4][4]` member which represents the matrix.

The updateCamera method has the following implementation:

```
cam->opm[0][0] = 2.0f / (right - left);
cam->opm[1][1] = 2.0f / (top - bottom);
cam->opm[2][2] = -2.0f / (zFar - zNear);
cam->opm[3][0] = -(right + left) / (right - left);
cam->opm[3][1] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
cam->opm[3][2] = -(zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
cam->opm[3][3] = 1.0f;
```

Everything is drawn correctly if I use an identity matrix instead of the one above. Perhaps there is an issue in my calculation of the matrix?

Comment: why not use http://glm.g-truc.net/ ? It makes much much more intuitive to create your matrix from scratch!

Comment: While glm is a great library and it works perfectly fine for me in other projects, this is a small project for me to learn how everything works in regard to these matrices. I find that knowledge useful.

Comment: I understand, but GLM is a very light library. You can use then while still understanding what is behind the scenes... but if you really wanna make yours, first make a Matrix class so you can multiply the matrices... then work on your logic with the separated steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the definition of the vertices and the call to `updateCamera`.

The triangle is so small that it is not drawn with those parameters.

Using the following draw call:

```
updateCamera(&gCamera, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
```

everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Use an identity matrix first to find out if drawing works - then add scaling and translation.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I have found the issue and answered my own question.